# A divisibility problem from Titu Andreescu.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> **Problem 1.1.2.** *Let $p > 2$ be an odd number and let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that $p$ divides $1^{p^n} + 2^{p^n} + \cdots + (p-1)^{p^n}$.*
>
> **Solution.** Define $k = p^n$ and note that $k$ is odd. Then
> $$d^k + (p-d)^k = p[d^{k-1} - d^{k-2}(p-d) + \cdots + (p-d)^{k-1}]$$
> Summing up the equalities from $d = 1$ to $d = \dfrac{p-1}{2}$ implies that $p$ divides $1^k + 2^k + \cdots + (p-1)^k$, as claimed.

I am trying to understand this divisibility question. I don't understand the 2nd line of the solution. What is $d$ here and what is the value of $d$? And in the 2nd line on the RHS, under the brackets, the sign of the 2nd term may be plus. Please can anyone explain it? Thank you.

Source: *Number Theory Structures, Examples and Problems* by Titu Andreescu and Dorin Andrica.

Comment: An easier solution: $d^{p^n}=(\cdots((d^p)^p)\cdots)^p\equiv d$ modulo $p$, etc.  Though as the problem is numbered 1.1.2, quite likely the book hasn't reached modular arithmetic yet.

Comment: To answer your question, $d$ is an arbitrary positive integer.  The point is simply that the only terms of the sum that don't include a multiple of $p$; namely, $d^k$ and the $d^k$ term of the power, cancel each other out so that what's left is a sum of multiples of $p$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define $S\equiv 1^{p^n}+...+(p-1)^{p^n}$ and per the answer let $k=p^n$ then
$$
S = (1^k+(p-1)^k)+(2^k+(p-2)^k)+...+(d^k+(p-d)^k)+...
$$
Since $p-1$ is even, all of the terms are paired.

Now
$$
\begin{align}
(d^k+(p-d)^k)&=d^k+p^k-kp^{k-1}d+...+kpd^{k-1}-d^k\\
&=
p\times\left(\text{some integer}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$
because the $d^k$ factors cancel for all values of $d$, so
$$
\begin{align}
S
&=
p\times\text{some integer}+p\times\text{another integer}+p\times\text{another integer}+...
\\
&=p\times\text{some integer},
\end{align}
$$
so $p\mid S$.

> What is d here and what is the value of d?

$d$ may be any of the numbers from 1 to $(p-1)/2$.

> And in the 2nd line on the RHS, under the brackets, the sign of the 2nd term may be plus.

With an ellipsis, $...$, it's common to write $+...+$ even if the sign may actually be negative.

Comment: I belive the OP means that  $ - d^{k - 2} (p - d)$ should be $+d^{k - 2} (p - d)$ (which is incorrect).